# Why do I get "Variable Expected" compiler error?

Tags: inno-setup, pascalscript

I'm trying to get the drive letter of the install path in Inno Setup without the colon and if the drive letter is C, it will return a null string.

Calling the function:

```
{code:GetDriveLetter|{drive:{src}}
```

Function:

```
function GetDriveLetter(DriveLetter: string): string;
var
  len: Integer;
begin
  len := CompareText(UpperCase(DriveLetter), 'C');
  if len = 0 then
  begin
    Result := '';
  end
  else
  begin
    Result := Delete(UpperCase(DriveLetter), 2, 1);
  end;
end;
```

I'm getting the compiler error:

> Variable Expected

on this line:

```
Result := Delete(UpperCase(DriveLetter), 2, 1);
```

What's the problem with that line? How can I fix this function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The *Variable Expected* compiler error you got because [`Delete`](http://www.jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=isxfunc_delete) is a procedure into which you are expected to pass a declared `string` type variable (which is then internally modified). And you are not passing a variable but an intermediate result of the `UpperCase` function call. So to fix this error you can either declare a variable, or use the predeclared `Result` one, e.g.:

```
var
  S: string;
begin
  S := UpperCase('a');
  Delete(S, 2, 1);
end;
```

Except that I would point out a few things. `Delete` is a `procedure`, and as such doesn't return any value, so even if you'd pass there a declared variable, you'd fail on a non-existing result assignment. The `CompareText` function is already a case insensitive comparison, so there's no need for upper-casing the input. And except that I would not compare the whole input (which is e.g. `C:` as returned by the `drive:` constant), but only the first character (but it depends on how safe you want to make your function). For only the first character comparison I would write something like this:

```
[Code]
function GetDriveLetter(Drive: string): string;
begin
  // we will upper case the first letter of the Drive parameter (if that parameter is
  // empty, we'll get an empty result)
  Result := UpperCase(Copy(Drive, 1, 1));
  // now check if the previous operation succeeded and we have in our Result variable
  // exactly 1 char and if we have, check if that char is the one for which we want to
  // return an empty string; if that is so, return an empty string
  if (Length(Result) = 1) and (Result[1] = 'C') then
    Result := '';
end;
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you want something like this?

```
[Code]
function GetDriveLetter(DriveLetter: string): string;
begin
if CompareStr(DriveLetter, 'C:\') = 0 then
  begin   
    Result := '';
  end
  else begin
    Result := Copy(DriveLetter, 1, 1);
  end
end;
```

But your example is not for install path but for installer source path...